# What is the necessity of arc management in a circuit breaker?

Tags: arc

Why is an arc management necessary in a circuit breaker?

Comment: Where did you get the information that arc formation is necessary in circuit breakers? As far as my knowledge goes, it is the exact opposite, to the point where very high power circuit breakers have powerful fans to literally blow away the plasma that allows an arc to be sustained.

Comment: If there is an arc the circuit is not broken. Also arc -> energy dissipation -> bad -> dead breaker if arc not removed.

Answer (score 3):

Arc formation is not *necessary* in a circuit breaker. It is an undesirable but depending on current carried, *unavoidable* aspect of circuit breakers.

Arcs are generated when the flow of current is interrupted. A circuit breaker should incorporate a way to contain and extinguish this arc, and keep the device cool while the arc exists.

Hence, a better question might be, "why is arc **management** necessary in a circuit breaker?"

Comment: An arc means that you have *failed* to interrupt the current!

Comment: @DaveTweed Yup. Hence the extinguishing part :-)